# MATLAB Drawing a function which takes vectors as an arguement

Tags: matlab

I want to draw an anonymous function in MATLAB which takes vectors as arguments. Does anyone know a solution?

Here is the example.

```
k=@( x1 , x2 ) exp(-C*sum((x1*ones(1,size(x2,2))-x2).^2)/0.5)'; 
wphi = @(xstar) ones(1,N)*(a.*y'.*k(xstar,x));
ystar=@(xstar)wphi(xstar)+b;
```

I want to draw ystar function. However; xstar is a vector with size 2. Whenever I use a drawing function like ezplot, it assumes xstar as a double variable. As I summarize; I want to draw ystar function, for example in the interval of (-1,-1) to (1,1) for xstar.

Comment: Yes. I solved the problem with few modification to your code. Thank you for the response. I cannot up vote you because I do not have enough reputation points.

Comment: Great! :-) Then please "accept" the question (click empty checkmark on left side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really test this, because there are a lot of things undefined in your code, and I can only assume your functions do work. But in principle, this should work:

```
xsv = linspace(-1, 1, 100);
[xstar1, xstar2] = meshgrid(xsv);
xstar = [xstar1(:), xstar2(:)];
surf(xstar1, xstar2, reshape(ystar(xstar), size(xstar1)))
```